# Kinvey server setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, webserver, kinvey

Kinvey is Backend as a Service | Mobile Cloud Backend as a Service

Is Kinvey ( http://www.kinvey.com/ ) good, or using custom Java server with database a good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a member of the Kinvey engineering team, and can talk a bit about BaaS in general.  While creating your own backend gives you a lot of flexibility and control, it is also a lot of work.

Back-end as a service providers like Kinvey offer a platform to speed up app development and have already done a lot of the work for you.  Tasks like managing a database server and a web service front-end, managing the storage and streaming of files, providing a cross-platform push notification, providing a centralized user and authentication store, integration with social networks, buisiness logic and more are easily implemented with SDKs for each platform.

If I were to list the three main advantages of BaaS, they are:

- Ease of implementation
- Ready-made back-end platform for cross-platform apps
- Automatic scalability if your app becomes successful

As far as disadvantages, your backend feature set becomes dependent on the vendor, and you certainly get more flexibility with a custom solution, but that can often be overcome with business logic.  In my own (admittedly biased) opinion, the flexibility and cost savings make it worth at least giving BaaS a try seeing if the feature sets meet your specific needs.

Comment: Yes, its easy to use Kinvey when compared to own backend. But, I will need to try how easy it is to write our own business logic.

Comment: For Kinvey, server-side business logic is written in Javascript through the developer console.  Logic can be attached to pre-process or post-process events for any request.  A brief introduction to business logic with kinvey can be found  at http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/tutorials/bl-getting-started.